# If $X_i$ is a log-normal r.v., show $X=\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is also a log-normal r.v.

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, normal-distribution

> A random variable $X$ has log-normal distribution if $Y=ln(X)$ has a normal distribution with density function 
>   $$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(y=\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \ \ \ \ y\in(-\infty,\infty)$$

I have calculated that the density function of $X$ is
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(lnx-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x>0$$

> If the $X_i$ are independent log-normal random variables, show that the product $X=\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is also a log-normal random variable.

I thought that if I could find the density function, $f_{X_i}(x_i)$, I could deduce the answer.

I took $$X=X^n_i$$
So
$$f_{X_i}(x_i)=f_X(x_i)\Big|\frac{dx}{dx_i}\Big|=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(lnx_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}x^{n-2}_i \ \ \ \ \ \ 
 \ \ \ x_i>0$$
Which I looks similar to what I was expecting (a density function of a log-normal random variable).

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$\ln(\prod_{i=1}^nX_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(X_i)$

Note that $\ln(X_i)$ have normal distribution and the $\ln(X_i)$ are independent.

Then what can be said of the sum?

Comment: That is a result I did not consider. Hence the sum of $X_i$ is a log-normal r.v?

Comment: The sum of the $\ln(X_i)$ is normal so the product of the $X_i$ is log-normal.

Comment: The only thing I don't quite get is why is the sum of $ln(X_i)$ normal? Is this because a sum of normal random variables is also a normal random variable?

Comment: @Bell When they are iid (independent and identically distributed), yes.

Comment: For that have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation). Btw, independence (or equal distribution) is not even necessary. A joint normal distribution is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use mgf's:

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{t\prod_{i=1}^nX_i}]=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[e^{tX_i}]$$

by independence

Then use the uniqueness theorem for mgf's

Comment: MGF of a lognormal distribution does not exist